# jQuery, JavaScript - How to create function that checks if form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
if($('input[name=id]').length == 1 && $('input[name=submitted]').length != 1 )
    {
    var id = $('input[name=id]').val(),
    name =  $('input[name=staro_ime]').val();
    img_upload(name, id);
    }
```

When form is submitted, hidden input field with name **submitted** is created. How can I check when form is submitted and then disable code from above?(This function is outside **submit_event**).

Answer (score 0):

just add a submit event to the form.

```
$('#your_form').on('submit',function() {
  $('#your_form').append("<input type='hidden' id='hidden_form' name='submitted' value='something' />");
}
```

if you want to just run the function once, you can use a variable out side of the event that you set, or you can just check if the appended field exists in the form. using the variable method:

```
var formSubmitted = false;
$('#your_form').on('submit',function() {
  if(!formSubmitted) {
    $('#your_form').append("<input type='hidden' id='hidden_form' name='submitted' value='something' />");
    //anything else you want to run one time

    formSubmitted = true;
    $('#your_form').submit();
  } else {
    //submit form
}
```

Comment: I have submit event, that is not the problem. The problem is that the function is outside the submit event. In your case, returning true will do nothing for the outside functions.